# ignoreUrlParams AEM Dispatcher

Tags: aem

We have a situation to cache the html page even thought there is query parameter in the URL. Example: domain.com/test/test1?a=b&c=d, in this URL test.html must be cached and this can be achieved by "ignoreUrlParams" to ignore the query strings. However, that is not working as expected and the test page is not being cached. Also, when the URL with query parameter(s) is accessed the result is a 404. When the test.html is accessed first and create a manual cache for test.html the URL with query parameter works perfectly fine. Any suggestions?

We are on dispatcher-apache2.2-4.2.3.so. Thank you.

Comment: Please see this answer: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2327014

Comment: I think you might mess something with rewrites on apache. Maybe you are adding html at the end of query string (domain.com/test/test1?a=b&c=d.html) or not adding it at all? Have you tried also to invoke domain.com/test/test1.html?a=b&c=d ? And one last question, have you ignored the all query parameters (a & c in this case) or only one of them?

Answer (score 0):

You can add as below -

```
/ignoreUrlParams {
/0001 { /glob "*" /type "deny" }
/0002 { /glob "query" /url "domain.com/test/test1" /type "allow" }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).